# How can I input current user_id into django database table?

Tags: python, ajax, django, sqlite

I'm trying to create editable table in user interface and everything works till I try to insert new model argument like:

usr=models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

after that getting this kind of error: django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: devices_device.usr_id

I'm trying to implement this because when I save my data every user can see it. But goal is to separate users information. Maybe there is an easier way to do it.

Using django 1.11.10 version

Models.py

```
class Device(models.Model):
  usr = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  ip = models.CharField(max_length=50)
  port_number = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

Views.py

```
def save_device_form(request, form, template_name):
    data = dict()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            data['form_is_valid'] = True
            devices = Device.objects.all()
            data['html_device_list'] = render_to_string('devices/additional/partial_devices_list.html', {
                'devices': devices
            })
        else:
            data['form_is_valid'] = False
    context = {'form': form}
    data['html_form'] = render_to_string(template_name, context, request=request)
    return JsonResponse(data)


def device_create(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DeviceForm(request.POST)
    else:
        form = DeviceForm()
    return save_device_form(request, form, 'devices/additional/partial_device_create.html')
```

UPDATED:

partial_device_create.html

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'device_create' %}" class="js-device-create-form">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
    <h4 class="modal-title"> Create new device </h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    {% include 'devices/additional/partial_device_form.html' %}
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal"> Uždaryti </button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"> Pridėti </button>
  </div>
</form>
```

save_device_form.html

```
{% load widget_tweaks %}

{% for field in form %}
  <div class="form-group{% if field.errors %} has-error{% endif %}">
    <label for="{{ field.id_for_label }}">{{ field.label }}</label>
    {% render_field field class="form-control" %}
    {% for error in field.errors %}
      <p class="help-block">{{ error }}</p>
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def save_device_form(request, form, template_name):
    data = dict()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            form = form.save(commit=False) # < use these 3 below lines for save data
            form.usr = request.user
            form.save()
```

According to your device model that need **usr** also So you need to save usr as i did in my code

Comment: thanks for fast answer! but unfortunately now have TypeError: 'Device' object is not iterable

Comment: .......
File "C:\Users\lukas\Desktop\WiFi Controller\valdiklis\devices\views.py", line 41, in device_create
    return save_device_form(request, form, 'devices/additional/partial_device_create.html')
  File "C:\Users\lukas\Desktop\WiFi Controller\valdiklis\devices\views.py", line 29, in save_device_form
    data['html_form'] = render_to_string(template_name, context, request=request)
  File "C:\Users\lukas\Anaconda3\envs\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py", line 68, in render_to_string ........

Comment: you have issue in template code. render_to_string template not getting iterator device object